# Does the default Chromium in puppeteer send telemetry to third party?

Tags: puppeteer

If using the default Chromium that is downloaded when installing puppeteer as explained [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer#installation), does this instance by default send any telemetry (usage data...) to a third party, such as Google? I couldn't find information on that, but my guess would be 'no', as most Google-specific features are active in Chrome, on top of Chromium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some user [reported](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=795526) Chromium sends some small data to google servers and the issues are marked as WontFix because that's how it was designed. Mostly it connects to translation servers to check available translations.

The [ungoogled-chromium](https://github.com/Eloston/ungoogled-chromium) project has even more strict privacy settings.